# Modify global CSS using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I know it's possible to modify an element's style attribute using JavaScript, but is it possible to modify the global CSS rule itself? Take the following example:

```
$('div.test').css('display', 'none');
```

That modifies all pre-existing elements matching:

```
<div class="test"></div>
```

If this script were executed while a page was half loaded the DOM tree would not be complete and any matching elements not loaded wouldn't have this styling rule applied. Is there a way to modify the actual *div.test* rule itself using JavaScript?

By the way, I do have my own solution to this and am not asking for any workarounds. I would just like to know if this in particular is possible since I've never seen it done before.

Comment: Why not just `$('.test').hide();`

Comment: The key is that not all elements are loaded into the DOM yet.

Comment: That would work if the page were already loaded in memory.

Comment: $("head").append("<style>.test{display:none}</style>")